# How to return from within an observer?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

I was trying to return filter function but return doesn't seem to work with callbacks. Here `this.store.let(getIsPersonalized$)` is an observable emitting boolean values and `this.store.let(getPlayerSearchResults$)` is an observable emiting objects of video class.
How do I run this synchronously, can I avoid asynchronus callback altogether given that I can't modify the observables received from store.

```
isPersonalized$ = this.store.let(getIsPersonalized$);
videos$ = this.store.let(getPlayerSearchResults$)                       
                    .map((vids) => this.myFilter(vids));

myFilter(vids) {
   this.isPersonalized$.subscribe((x){
      if(x){
         return this.fileterX(vids);//Return from here
      }
      else {
         return this.filterY(vids);//Or Return from here
      }
  });
}

fileterX(vids) {
  return vids.filter((vid) => vids.views>100;);
}

fileterY(vids) {
  return vids.filter((vid) => vids.views<20;);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way, you don't need myFilter(vids) at all if you can get the branching out on `isPersonalized$`'s subscribe. Here is the updated code.

```
  this.store.let(getIsPersonalized$);
  videos$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isPersonalized$.subscribe((x) => {
      if (x) {
        this.videos$ = this.store.let(getPlayerSearchResults$)
                        .map((vids) => this. fileterX(vids));
      } else {
        this.videos$ = this.store.let(getPlayerSearchResults$)
                        .map((vids) => this. fileterY(vids));
      }
    });
  }

  fileterX(vids) {
    return vids.filter((vid) => vids.views>100;);
  }

  fileterY(vids) {
    return vids.filter((vid) => vids.views<20;);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to evaluate the latest value of `isPersonalized$` within the map function, i'd do that via `withLatestFrom` (Example: The first one toggles `true/false` every 5s, the second emits an increasing number every 1s):

```
const isPersonalized$ = Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
  .map(value => value % 2 === 0);
const getPlayerSearchResults$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .withLatestFrom(isPersonalized$)
  .map(bothValues => {
    const searchResult = bothValues[0];
    const isPersonalized = bothValues[1];
    ...
  });
```